# How to pass pointer to array of byte to function?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to pass pointer to data into function. But I am getting error Incompatible types: 'Array' and 'TBytes'. I cannot find out how to fix it.

```
type TBytes = array of byte;
type PTBytes = ^TBytes;

procedure Dictionary.WriteData(Data: PTBytes);
begin
  try
    DataStream.Write(Data[0], sec[sid].grp[grp].META.dataLength);
  finally
  end;
end;
```

Previously I tried

```
pData: ^TBytes;
PData := Data^;
```

Finally I call

```
writeData( data);
```

But it generates error Pointer type required

**Edit**

I have replaced the procedure appendData to writeData. It is easer now.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to name the pointer type `PBytes`. (More generally, given a type `TMyThing`, we often define `PMyThing = ^TMyThing`.)

Comment: But you don't use `pData` at all. It would better to describe real problem.

Comment: A variable of `TBytes` is a pointer in itself.

Comment: I think you should at least edit your code (and the answer you have accepted) so that they are less nonsensical (making no use of the input data and uselessly operating on a local variable).  Meanwhile -1 and VTC.

Comment: @MartynA: The question updated. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: @ MBo . Thanks for note, code updated. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because IVO GELOV did not updated his code and/or did not removed his answer, I am adding my current code, which I am using.

type TBytes = array of byte;

procedure Dictionary.WriteData(var Data: TBytes);

```
begin
  try
    DataStream.Write(Data[0], sec[sid].grp[grp].META.dataLength);
  finally
  end;
end;
```